# how to retrieve the last unique object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, indexing

Hey guys is there a way i can retrieve the last unique object in an array
in the code below the id at the first and second index are the same is there a way i can retrieve the last occurrence of the id with the corresponding object

```
0: {id: 'tra.528555295', name: 'heart'}
1: {id: 'tra.528555295', name: 'heart-outline'}
2: {id: 'tra.528555301', name: 'heart'}
3: {id: 'tra.528555301', name: 'heart-outline'}
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @goto i just need the object where the similar id's occurs last in the array like in the code i gave the object at index 1 and index 3 should be returned

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate through the entire array and keep track of the "last" object with that unique `ID` found.

Here's one way you can do it using `Array.prototype.reduce` to iterate through the array and keep track of the "last" `ID` found, then pulling values with unique `ID`s using `Object.values`:

```js
const arr = [
  { id: "tra.528555295", name: "heart" },
  { id: "tra.528555295", name: "heart-outline" },
  { id: "tra.528555301", name: "heart" },
  { id: "tra.528555301", name: "heart-outline" }
];

const result = Object.values(
  arr.reduce((accumulator, item) => {
    const { id, ...rest } = item;
    return {
      ...accumulator,
      [id]: { id, ...rest }
    };
  }, {})
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide the id I suggest:

```
const findLastElementOfId = (arr, id) => {
    return arr.filter(object => object.id === id).at(-1)
}
```

filter the array for the objects with the id you are looking for and return the last one.